# Automatically Dismissing/Closing Custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-progressbar

I have this custom dialog:

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context) {
        MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
                android.R.color.transparent);
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }

    public static void dismiss(Context context) {
        MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

It will show

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        MyProgressDialog.show(ItemsActivity.this);
        }
```

but will not dismiss with:

```
MyProgressDialog.dismiss(ItemsActivity.this);
```

does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new dialog and dismissing that, not the one you created in `show()`. You can keep a reference to the latest dialog created and dismiss that if you'd like. For example:

```
public static MyProgressDialog show(Context context) {
    MyProgressDialog dialog = new MyProgressDialog(context);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
            android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.show();
    staticVariable = dialog;
    return staticVariable;
}

public static void dismiss(Context context) {
    staticVariable.dismiss();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem like an ideal design.

Comment: Would it be better to just not do it statically?

Comment: Yes, a better idea would be to keep the dialog reference where you need it. Then instead of having a static `dismiss()` method you can get the one you created and dismiss it when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: The problem with the static reference is that it's not smart enough, if you show two then you will never be able to hide the first one. You could make it smarter but you should just keep a reference where you spawned it.

Comment: thanks for your help. Redoing it without static got everything working. Marked correct!